# Day over Day Change is not calculating correctly

Tags: powerbi

I have created a measure below to calculate the day over day value change (Current MTM - Previous Day MTM) between 2 dates (in this case, 10/26 to 10/25).  The issue is the overall change is correct, but when you look at the data that is rolled up by category (i.e.,cOptimization) the change is not calculating correct because there was not a value for 10/25 (new data came in on 10/26).  My question is how do I get this measure to work on the category level (cOptimization)?  Here is the measure that I created...

```
D-o-D MTM Change = =
     IF (
         OR ( ISBLANK ( [Previous MTM] ), [Previous MTM] = 0 ),
         BLANK (),
         [Current MTM] - [Previous MTM]
     )
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an .pbix file as example?